# How to remove XAMPP but keep its modules like mysql?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use XAMPP to host my MySQL database. After I did "ALTER ADD COLUMNS" operation, I can't connect MySQL by phpmyadmin anymore.

My phpmyadmin have some error like image.

[image]
I tried to remove xampp but it seems will also remove mysql but I want to keep my data alive.

How to I remove just XAMPP and keep my data in mysql safe? Or did I have any method to fix this error?

I use Unity C# to send MySQL "ALTER" query like below.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    string query = "";

    query += "ALTER TABLE solutions_" + i + " ADD  ";
    query += "tail_length FLOAT";
    query += ";";

    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Why not taking a backup of the database, remove XAMPP, reinstall it, re-create the database restoring from the backup?

Comment: OK. I will try it. Thanks!